# Does It cost money for a new launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to update my game to the 1.7.2 update, but I am wondering, does it cost money to download a new launcher?

Answer (score 11):

**No.** Once you have purchased Minecraft once, you own all future versions of the game on that particular platform. Updating will never cost anything.

Worth noting is that Mojang have only ever *explicitly* said that future versions will never cost anything for users who purchased the alpha version. However, no update so far has ever costed anything for anyone, and Mojang have earlier voiced the opinion that updates never should be paid.

Comment: This isn't true. Mojang has guaranteed that *alpha* users will get every update for free, forever, but people who got their accounts during beta or later do not get this guarantee. Mojang will *probably* never charge for updates, but they have explicitly said that they will not promise it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I decided not to mention the special cases regarding when you purchased the game. Not to spread misinformation, but rather because no update so far has cost anything, and Mojang has earlier voiced the opinion that they'd like to keep updates free.

Comment: Yeah, they'd like to, but "never" doesn't really match "sorry, our lawyers made us stop guaranteeing that."

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Okay, just for the sake of covering all bases, I'll update my answer.

Comment: You own all future versions of the game *for that platform*. If you want it on Android, iOS, Xbox or (eventually?) PSN you'll have to buy it again, of course. Because pedantry is fun.

Comment: @TZHX Sigh. Your pedantry has paid off.

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft's *launcher* has never cost money – it's getting a Minecraft premium account that costs. (If you have ever paid for just the *launcher*, I'm afraid you were probably scammed.) A premium account is required to login with the new launcher.

The new launcher can be [downloaded from Minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/download). This is the exact same place the old launcher was downloaded from.

Answer (score -2):

Updates (so far) don't cost money. Don't give them any ideas, though.

The original account is what you pay for, I guess the updates are an added bonus.

Comment: It's like Mojang is a greedy corporation, or if they don't know of charging for updates practice. It's never gonna happen.